# Nullpointer Exception in testNG data provider while executing through Jenkins job

Tags: java, eclipse, jenkins, testng, testng-dataprovider

I'm trying to execute my testng test which has data provider defined through Jenkins Job. I'm facing below null pointer exception. But, same test case executing without any errors in my local machine (from Eclipse)

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException

Message: java.lang.NullPointerException

Stacktrace:

at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:161)
at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:429)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1224)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1149)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1057)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGExecutor.run(TestNGExecutor.java:295)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.execute(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:90)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)


Caused by: 
at com.MyTest.getDetails(GetDetailsTest.java:207)
at com.MyTest.sendValidParamters(GetDetailsTest.java:73)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:84)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:135)
... 23 more
```

---

My data provider is something like this :

```
    @DataProvider(name = "valid_parameters")
        public Object[][] sendValidParamters() throws Exception {

            return new Object[][] {
                    { getDetailsFromDB("getFromDB", true, "images/backgrnd.jpeg")},
getDetailsFromDB("getFromDB", true, "images/backgrnd.jpeg")}};
```

In which, I'm trying to fetch some rows from table based on parameters.

Comment: I think posting code would be a better idea than posting exception log. For a start.

Comment: check line 207 in `com.MyTest.getDetails#GetDetailsTest`. Something is null there.

Comment: modified question , added data provider (line 207 is call to getDetailsFromDB() method. In which I'm querying data from db.

Comment: Does your `jenkins` (which user running your job) user have the permission to access your DB ?

Comment: You should provide the content of `com.MyTest.getDetails()` method.